# Problems with Search API and Entity Translation

Tags: 7, search

I'm building a two-language website (Ukrainian - main, English - second) with the new Entity Translation approach. This approach seems very promising however it does not support multilingual content indexing.

I planned to use Search API Database Search module for the website. I also installed Search API Entity Translation and Search API Entity Translation Database Search in order to make them play together.

However the behaviour I achieved is the following:

**1. When searching the website from the Ukrainian version**: when searching with Ukrainian keywords the search yields no results; when searching with English keywords the search shows results in Ukrainian (the Ukrainian versions of relevant content in English).

**2. When searching the website from the English version**: when searching with Ukrainian keywords the search yields no results; when searching with English keywords the search shows results in English (with highlighted relevant keywords).

As far as I understand there is a problem with Ukrainian content indexing. Is it somehow possible to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to enable the "title_field" field in the Fields tab of the index instead of "title", as well as any other translatable fields you want indexed.  Then, make sure to re-index everything.

By default, custom fields aren't enabled there, and neither is "title_field" which provides translations of titles via the Title module.

Answer (score 0):

[**Search API Entity Translation**](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_et)

Search API Entity Translation module provides multilingual support for the Search API module through integration with Entity Translation.